# how to differentiate front-end's and back-end's common header and footer in codeigniter hmvc?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to use common header and footer for front-end / common header and footer for back-end in codeigniter HMVC. Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create a module where you can have your admin controllers and you can create header and footer controllers for that admin / back end and then you can do the same but just rename module for fronted

```
Modules::run('folder/folder/controllername/function');
```

or on you view

```
<?php echo Modules::run('folder/folder/controllername/function');?>
```

Doc's https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

For example admin back end module

```
application > modules 
application > modules > admin 
application > modules > admin > controllers > common
application > modules > admin > controllers > common > Header.php
application > modules > admin > controllers > common > Footer.php
application > modules > admin > controllers > example > Welcome.php
application > modules > admin > views > common > header.php
application > modules > admin > views > common > footer.php
application > modules > admin > views > example > welcome.php
```

URL Example `http://localhost/project/index.php/example/welcome`

Controller Admin Example

```
<?php

class Welcome extends MX_Controller {

public function index() {
   $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
   $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');
   $this->load->view('example/welcome_message', $data);
}

}
```

**Admin Header Controller**

```
<?php

class Header extends MX_Controller {

public function index() {
   // Create a header view in the module folder view
   return $this->load->view('common/header');
}

}
```

**Admin Footer Controller**

```
<?php

class Footer extends MX_Controller {

public function index() {
   // Create a footer view in the module folder view
   return $this->load->view('common/footer');
}

}
```

**HMVC View Example**

```
<?php echo $header;?>
Your Content
<?php echo $footer;?>
```

**Or**

```
<?php echo Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');?>
 Your Content
<?php echo Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');?>
```

When you need to change routes for HMVC Examples Only

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/common/home/index';

$route['admin'] = 'admin/common/login/index';
$route['somename'] 'module/folder/controller/function';
$route['somename/edit/(:any)'] 'module/folder/controller/function/$1';
$route['somename/edit/(:any)/(:any)'] 'module/folder/controller/function/$1/$2';
```